# findOne then findMany using value from document found in findOne, in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```js
const categorySlug = req.query.category;
const category = await Category.findOne({ slug: categorySlug });
const children = await Category.find({ parent: category._id });
```

Is it possible to combine those two queries into one? I tried doing something like

```js
const children = await Category.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          slug: categorySlug, 
        },
      },
      {
        // somehow use the _id field from document fetched in first stage 
      }
    ]);
```

But I have no idea if this is even possible.

EDIT:

```js
const document = await Category.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          slug: categorySlug,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'categories',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'parent',
          as: 'children',
        },
      },
    ]);

    const desiredResult = document[0].children;
```

This works but is there a way to do this fully in the aggregation pipeline? Basically I want to get ONLY the "children" array, nothing else.

EDIT2: The result of above query is this array with an object which has an array of objects

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
        "parent": null,
        "products": [
            "60515150d6ac5e08a4e796b4",
            "6051b8b0f8c80835480b28d3"
        ],
        "isParent": true,
        "name": "Electronics",
        "description": "All kinds of devices",
        "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:24:31.365Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-20T20:42:50.699Z",
        "slug": "electronics",
        "__v": 4,
        "children": [
            {
                "_id": "6051cb588f974b3104715ec5",
                "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
                "products": [],
                "isParent": true,
                "name": "Cameras",
                "description": "description",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:26:48.220Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-17T09:29:35.608Z",
                "slug": "cameras",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "6051cb5f8f974b3104715ec6",
                "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
                "products": [
                    "60515150d6ac5e08a4e796b4",
                    "6051b8b0f8c80835480b28d3"
                ],
                "isParent": true,
                "name": "Computers",
                "description": "description",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:26:55.364Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-20T20:42:50.779Z",
                "slug": "computers",
                "__v": 4
            },
            {
                "_id": "6051cb6f8f974b3104715ec7",
                "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
                "products": [],
                "isParent": false,
                "name": "Car Electronics",
                "description": "description",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:11.108Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:11.108Z",
                "slug": "car-electronics",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "6051cb768f974b3104715ec8",
                "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
                "products": [],
                "isParent": false,
                "name": "TV",
                "description": "description",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:18.422Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:18.422Z",
                "slug": "tv",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want to get is the whole "children" array inside that object

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "6051cb588f974b3104715ec5",
        "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
        "products": [],
        "isParent": true,
        "name": "Cameras",
        "description": "description",
        "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:26:48.220Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-17T09:29:35.608Z",
        "slug": "cameras",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6051cb5f8f974b3104715ec6",
        "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
        "products": [
            "60515150d6ac5e08a4e796b4",
            "6051b8b0f8c80835480b28d3"
        ],
        "isParent": true,
        "name": "Computers",
        "description": "description",
        "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:26:55.364Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-20T20:42:50.779Z",
        "slug": "computers",
        "__v": 4
    },
    {
        "_id": "6051cb6f8f974b3104715ec7",
        "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
        "products": [],
        "isParent": false,
        "name": "Car Electronics",
        "description": "description",
        "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:11.108Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:11.108Z",
        "slug": "car-electronics",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6051cb768f974b3104715ec8",
        "parent": "6051cacf8f974b3104715ec4",
        "products": [],
        "isParent": false,
        "name": "TV",
        "description": "description",
        "createdAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:18.422Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-17T09:27:18.422Z",
        "slug": "tv",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Like I mentioned this can be done with `const desiredResult = document[0].children;` but I would like to do this in the query itself.

EDIT3: It seems that aggregate will always return an array of documents even if there is only one document and I can choose how the documents will look like, however I can't only return a field itself, without the document. That's fine for what I'm trying to do - I can assign that document (or a specific field of it) to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

> MongoDB has the join-like $lookup aggregation operator in versions >= 3.2. Mongoose has a more powerful alternative called populate(), which lets you reference documents in other collections.

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). We may populate a single document, multiple documents, a plain object, multiple plain objects, or all objects returned from a query. Let's look at some examples.

---

get the full array

```
{ $project: { _id:0, children: 1 } }
```

Use this for getting 1st element

Extract the first element from the array in the aggregation project pipeline

```
{ $project: { _id:0, children: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$children", 0 ] } } }


if(document && document[0] && document[0].children) { // your logic }
```

[$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

combined query

```
const document = await Category.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      slug: categorySlug,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'categories',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'parent',
      as: 'children',
    },
  },
  { $project: { _id:0, children: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$children", 0 ] } } }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Learned something new, but unfortunately I want to get the whole "children" array. I updated my question to include an example of desired result.

Comment: @Krzysztof Updated the answer.

Comment: That's not it. I might've not been clear - I want ALL values from children array, the array itself. Basically to ONLY output the children array. The result should be an array with all objects from "children" array. As shown in EDIT#2. I managed to get the result I want outside the query, but I wonder it's possible to do within the query.

Comment: @Krzysztof aggregation returns array of elements by default

Comment: @Krzysztof you can use https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Unfortunately populate won't work with my data model. Documents don't reference children, only parent. So to find children of a document, I need to do ```Category.find({ parent: parent._id });```. The goal of my query is to first find the parent by its "name" field and then find children of that document. So I know that aggregation will always return ONE document. The goal is to output a field of that document ("children" array), not a whole document. But I guess it's impossible with how aggregate works, it seems to always return a document. Thanks for trying to help, I appreciate it.